# Problem with nicematrix package

Tags: nicematrix

Today I was using  `\nicematrix` package first time.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{array,xparse,l3keys2e,expl3} 
 \usepackage[fit]{tikz}
 \usepackage[transparent]{nicematrix}


\begin{document}    


\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}
 $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 \\
    0 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

I was wan not at all getting anything. Anybody, please tell me how to use `\nicematrix` package, if at all I am wrong.

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{array,xparse,l3keys2e,expl3} 
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}    

\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}
$ \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 \\
    0 & \ddots & & \vdots \\
    \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}`

Comment: Nothing happened. Even I have updated my code. See the updates one.

Comment: Are you able to compile your code? I couldn't compile yours and the code I posted is what compiled and gave an output.

Comment: Your code and mine are the same. I am unable to compile my code. I have included `nicematrix.sty` in the folder. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: Well, if you have the full TeX distribution installed on your machine, the `nicematrix` package should already be there. Also, you can't write `\usepackage[fit]{tikz}`, you have to change it to `\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{fit}`

Comment: You should copy and paste all the code that I posted in the first comment, from `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}` to `\end{document}` and test it

Comment: No, still I am not getting any output. The main thing is that it is not showing any error also. So that is why I am unable to identify the problem.

Comment: That is the problem, you might have issues with your compiler. I have Texmaker as the IDE and compiled using PDFLaTeX. You might want to try something else to compile with. Also I gotta sleep so I will be up in a few hours.

Comment: I also have Texmaker with PDFLaTeX. See the screenshot in the question. I am really sorry to bother you.

Comment: `nicematrix` package uses `l3` packages, you please update the `l3` packages and then try...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not compilable. You need to remove options from `tikz` as well from `nicematrix` packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % default wih recent article
\usepackage{mathtools}% also load amsmath
\usepackage{amssymb}  % also load amsfonts
\usepackage{array,xparse} 
% Why you load l3keys2e and expl3 packages? 
% Packages, which use them load those package themselves.
\usepackage{tikz}       % <---
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{nicematrix} % <---

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}
 \[
\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & \cdots & \cdots & 1      \\
     0 & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & \cdots & 0      & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, you need to compile above MWE at least twice. Is this what you looking for?

**Edit:**
Your matrix you can write also on the following (more sensible)  way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{nicematrix} 

\begin{document}

 \[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}
     1 & \Cdots & \Cdots & 1      \\
     0 & \Ddots &        & \Vdots \\
\Vdots & \Ddots & \Ddots & \Vdots \\
     0 & \Cdots & 0      & 1
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
     1 & \cdots & \cdots & 1      \\
     0 & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
     0 & \cdots & 0      & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

where for dotted lines inside matrix are used commands `Cdots`, `Ddots` and `Vdots` defined byh `nicematrix`. The advantage of using them instead of (global) setting `\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}` is that they only works in `{pNiceMatrix}` environments.

For comparison is added code for standard matrix. Result is:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I am getting an error message.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad, (i) you should tell us, what error you receive; (ii) probably  you have out-dated `nicematrix` or even complete LaTeX installation.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad, I add another option to use `nicematrix` math environment. Both example works with recent package version (version 3.0 from 2019/08/15)  as it is advertised .

Comment: `keyvalue error: "option-unknown" Unknown option 'transparent' for package . For immediate help type H <return>. \NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}` This is the message I am getting.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad, You have to old version of `nicematrix` package. Try example which I show in the edit part of answer, where are used `Cdor`, `Ddot` and `Vdot`.

Comment: Yes I did that and it worked well. Could you please tell me how to update the package `nicework`?

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad, I use MikTeX. It has utility "console" where I select "updates" and that is all. For other 
 distribution I do not know exactly, however, it not be to much different.

Comment: @SachchidanandPrasad, from time of writing answer till now was done many upgrades of this excellent package. Temporary I have version 6.8a from 2022/05/08.

Comment: I now have learnt to update the packages. Thanks to you. Yes, I noticed the update.